# Specify UserId Format When Creating Login Via OAuth2 With Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Perhaps Firebase gave me enough rope to hang myself with.

When creating a user via provided email and password, I am able to also provide the user_id.

Great. Since most of my primary keys in my database are uuid/guid, I thought it would be swell to make my user_id in my users table a uuid pk.

That worked.

Until I let the user authenticate via a third-party. Firebase came back having created my lovely user. With a Firebase UserId.

Which is not a uuid.

And now I find myself contemplating having to redesign the userId field in my database back to text type, because the Firebase UserId is not a uuid.

Is there a way to tell Firebase to make all user_id values be guids? I've poked around a wee bit but I don't see options when using OAuth2 to tell Firebase, "And when you come back with a user, make that user_id a uuid/guid, please..."

Edit: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I was/am using the Firebase UID as my pk, not, for example, the user's email address. But if I can only control the value/format of that UID when I'm providing email/pwd to create users (and not when authenticating via 3rd party OAuth2) then I cannot assume my preferred format.

2nd Edit:

When creating users via email/pwd, I do so via Firebase Admin SDK. The browser passes the email/pwd to the API, and the API creates the user--with full control over UID.

```
private async Task<UserRecord> AddFirebaseLogin(UserForCreation userForCreation)
{
  UserRecordArgs args = new UserRecordArgs()
  {
    Uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
...
```

However when the browser redirects to 3rd party OAuth, the UID comes back already in the authentication token, and I think I've missed my chance to say what format I'd like that UID to be in.

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
...
return this.afAuth.auth
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((res) => {
     this.ngZone.run(() => {
        const userData = {
          uid: res.user.uid,
...
```

I am thinking it's of small value to have the privilege of setting the UID when creating users directly in one situation if one does not have this level of control in any of the other authentication methods.

All I did was create heartache for myself when I ran with the freedoms afforded me when I was creating users myself with email/pwd.

Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're observing or what you're expecting that's different.  A Firebase UID are not technically a UUID.  It is its own unique identifying string, used only in the scope of Firebase Auth.

Comment: And... that's the problem, Doug. When I created the Firebase UID with email and password, I was able to *provide* the UID I wanted, and I made it a guid. That suited my database structure fine and I developed around it. Making the storage of that UID a UUID. Now come to find out I don't (appear to) have the option of specifying either the UID or even the format of said UID when I redirect Firebase to an OAuth provider. If I cannot do that, then I need to redesign my database UID field to accept whatever I get back, instead of demanding a UUID.

Comment: Typically people just accept the UID string from Firebase as it is.  I don't understand why you need to convert it to anything else.  You might want to relax your database schema to just accept strings as unique identifiers.

Comment: And... that's the solution, Doug. If I can't control Firebase UID values/formats. You'll forgive me for asking before I spend several hours doing just that. This is why I indicated I thought Firebase had given me enough rope to hang myself with. When I thought I had full control, I got the brilliant idea of using UUIDs. An idea I now regret.

Comment: This is exactly my problem also. Too much freedom, if partial, is worse than having a NO from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to control the content or format of the UIDs coming from Firebase Authentication.  It generates unique strings, and they need to be accepted as they are.  You can be sure they are unique within your project, and are safe to use as primary keys in a database.

Comment: What you're saying is not 100% true.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#c_1  Note the *if*: "If not provided, a random uid will be automatically generated." I provided UUIDs and all was well. Until. Until it wasn't. Anyway, I do accept that you're almost surely right where other login routes are concerned, and accept your answer, since you've been helpful enough to engage with the question. I guess I have some database work to do, today. Sigh. I wish Firebase had not allowed me to go down this primrose path.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show the code you're actually working with.  If you're saying that you're using the Firebase Admin SDK to create the user (as opposed to creating the user account using a client SDK), that needs to be clear.  With Firebase Admin, you can provide the ID, but it's still just a string, and it's up to you to make sure it's unique.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix that. Yeah, I can (and do) oversee email/pwd user creation--and I have control over UID in that scenario. But I don't seem to have that kind of control when accepting 3rd party OAuth authentication. At that point, I just get what I get. Or so it seems. I'll post a bit of code, to make my question more clear.

Comment: I don't see where you actually used the admin SDK to create the user account.  It looks like you are depending on the client code to sign in using the microsoft provider.  In that case, Firebase Auth will assign the UID automatically.

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm the author of the API code. (I create the Firebase user via SDK using `UserRecordArgs args` but I didn't see the need for that code to be included.) Someone else wrote the Angular code. But unless I'm mistaken, by the time Firebase comes back after the redirect to the MS OAuth2 authentication, the Firebase account already exists. That's part and parcel of the problem. I have no say in its creation until the ID already exists, at which point I *can't* create it or change it. I think it's a done deal I just need to make UID a text field and call it a day.

Comment: Assuming you're using Firestore as strings don't make good primary key values in relational database systems such as Cloud SQL Postgres. I suspect this is why @Wellspring chose to use UUIDs to link together his users tables and other tables with foreign keys pointing back to users. Having the current UID string format means having to use a surrogate key and maintain a mapping between the PK and the UID chosen by Firebase Auth.

Would be great if Firebase Auth sign-ups had an option for v4 UUIDs, or better allow a custom JS function resolving to whatever key generation method devs chose.